# Appcelerator Titanium Map View - Show Annotation Title By Default

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I have a map view:

```
<View id='map' class='smallMap' module='ti.map' />
```

I set it up:

```
$.map.setRegion({
    latitude: r.y,
    longitude: r.x,
    latitudeDelta: 0.1,
    longitudeDelta: 0.1
});
```

I add an annotation:

```
var annotation = mapModule.createAnnotation({
    latitude: x,
    longitude: y,
    title: location.street,
});
$.map.addAnnotation(annotation);
```

The latest docs say this:

> An annotation has two states: selected and deselected. A deselected annotation is marked by a pin image. When the user selects the pin, the full annotation is displayed.

Is there a way to cause the default state of the annotation to be selected, or to select it without user interaction.  Using `annotation.fireEvent('click')` was a bust.  Must I overlay a custom view onto the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the selectAnnotation method, example:

```
$.map.selectAnnotation(annotation);
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple and difficult to find in the docs!

Comment: Something along the same lines, is there a way to detect when the user clicks on the popup that shows up when the annotation is selected?